# inserting into temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

In first step i am creating structure of the table, Second step i am inserting data from one table into the 1st table, third step also i am inserting data from another table to first table, fourth step i am displaying d inserted data. But this procedure is not working. Can u plz tel me where i am goin wrong

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[ISP_ANNEXURE_10]

@SDATE SMALLDATETIME,@EDATE SMALLDATETIME,           
@SAC AS VARCHAR(60),@EAC AS VARCHAR(60)            
,@SIT AS VARCHAR(100),@EIT AS VARCHAR(100)

AS            

BEGIN          


SELECT PEMAIN.TRAN_CD,PEMAIN.TRAN_DT,PEMAIN.TRAN_NO,           
PEMAIN.BILL_NO,PEMAIN.BILL_DT, PEMAIN.[RULE],
CM_MAST.AC_NM,PEMAIN.CONS_NM,PEMAIN.NET_AMT,PEITEM.QTY,
PEITEM.RATE,PEMAIN.GRO_AMT,   PEITEM.ASSES_AMT,PEITEM.EXAMTPER,PEITEM.EXAMT,PEITEM.CESSPER,PEITEM.CESS_AMT,   PEMAIN.SHCESSPER,PEITEM.SHCESS_AMT,PEITEM.PROD_NM,CM_MAST.ECC_NO,CM_MAST.VEND_NM,
PT_MAST.CHAP_NM 
    INTO #ANNXR10 
    FROM PEMAIN INNER JOIN PEITEM  ON (PEMAIN.TRAN_CD=PEITEM.TRAN_CD AND PEMAIN.TRAN_ID=PEITEM.TRAN_ID) 
    INNER JOIN PT_MAST ON (PEITEM.PROD_CD=PT_MAST.PROD_CD) 
    INNER JOIN CM_MAST ON (PEMAIN.AC_ID=CM_MAST.AC_ID)
    WHERE 1=2



    INSERT INTO #ANNXR10 SELECT PEMAIN.TRAN_CD,PEMAIN.TRAN_DT,PEMAIN.TRAN_NO, PEMAIN.BILL_NO,PEMAIN.BILL_DT,PEMAIN.[RULE],
    CM_MAST.AC_NM,PEMAIN.CONS_NM,PEMAIN.NET_AMT,PEITEM.QTY,PEITEM.RATE,PEMAIN.GRO_AMT,
    PEITEM.ASSES_AMT,PEITEM.EXAMTPER,PEITEM.EXAMT,PEITEM.CESSPER,PEITEM.CESS_AMT,
    PEMAIN.SHCESSPER,PEITEM.SHCESS_AMT,PEITEM.PROD_NM,CM_MAST.ECC_NO,CM_MAST.VEND_NM,PT_MAST.CHAP_NM 
    FROM PEMAIN INNER JOIN PEITEM  ON (PEMAIN.TRAN_CD=PEITEM.TRAN_CD AND PEMAIN.TRAN_ID=PEITEM.TRAN_ID) 
    INNER JOIN PT_MAST ON (PEITEM.PROD_CD=PT_MAST.PROD_CD) 
    INNER JOIN CM_MAST ON (PEMAIN.AC_ID=CM_MAST.AC_ID)


    INSERT INTO #ANNXR10 SELECT    SRMAIN.TRAN_CD,SRMAIN.TRAN_DT,SRMAIN.TRAN_NO,'','',SRMAIN.[RULE],
    CM_MAST.AC_NM,SRMAIN.CONS_NM,SRMAIN.NET_AMT,SRITEM.QTY,SRITEM.RATE,SRMAIN.GRO_AMT,
    SRITEM.ASSES_AMT,SRITEM.EXAMTPER,SRITEM.EXAMT,SRITEM.CESSPER,SRITEM.CESS_AMT,
    SRMAIN.SHCESSPER,SRITEM.SHCESS_AMT,SRITEM.PROD_NM,CM_MAST.ECC_NO,CM_MAST.VEND_NM,PT_MAST.CHAP_NM 
    FROM SRMAIN INNER JOIN SRITEM  ON (SRMAIN.TRAN_CD=SRITEM.TRAN_CD AND SRMAIN.TRAN_ID=SRITEM.TRAN_ID) 
    INNER JOIN PT_MAST ON (SRITEM.PROD_CD=PT_MAST.PROD_CD) 
    INNER JOIN CM_MAST ON (SRMAIN.AC_ID=CM_MAST.AC_ID)


    SELECT A10.TRAN_CD,A10.TRAN_DT,A10.TRAN_NO, A10.BILL_NO,A10.BILL_DT, A10.[RULE],
    A10.AC_NM,A10.CONS_NM,A10.NET_AMT,A10.QTY,A10.RATE,A10.GRO_AMT,
    A10.ASSES_AMT,A10.EXAMTPER,A10.EXAMT,A10.CESSPER,A10.CESS_AMT,
    A10.SHCESSPER,A10.SHCESS_AMT,A10.PROD_NM,A10.ECC_NO,A10.VEND_NM,A10.CHAP_NM 
    FROM #ANNXR10 A10
    WHERE A10.TRAN_CD IN('PE','SR') AND A10.[RULE]='EXCISABLE' 
    AND A10.TRAN_DT BETWEEN @SDATE AND @EDATE
    AND A10.AC_NM BETWEEN @SAC AND @EAC
    AND A10.PROD_NM BETWEEN @SIT AND @EIT


DROP TABLE #ANNXR10


END
```

Comment: "not working" is not a really helpful diagnostic. Have you got error messages, nothing displayed, anything else ?

Comment: by the way, I'm a little bit surprise by the `WHERE 1=2` clause...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus SELECT INTO with impossible WHERE is used to create empty table. TOP 0 can also work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ISP_ANNEXURE_10] 

      @SDATE SMALLDATETIME
    , @EDATE SMALLDATETIME
    , @SAC AS VARCHAR(60)
    , @EAC AS VARCHAR(60)
    , @SIT AS VARCHAR(100)
    , @EIT AS VARCHAR(100)

AS BEGIN

    SELECT  A10.TRAN_CD
        ,   A10.TRAN_DT
        ,   A10.TRAN_NO
        ,   A10.BILL_NO
        ,   A10.BILL_DT
        ,   A10.[RULE]
        ,   A10.AC_NM
        ,   A10.CONS_NM
        ,   A10.NET_AMT
        ,   A10.QTY
        ,   A10.Rate
        ,   A10.GRO_AMT
        ,   A10.ASSES_AMT
        ,   A10.EXAMTPER
        ,   A10.EXAMT
        ,   A10.CESSPER
        ,   A10.CESS_AMT
        ,   A10.SHCESSPER
        ,   A10.SHCESS_AMT
        ,   A10.PROD_NM
        ,   A10.ECC_NO
        ,   A10.VEND_NM
        ,   A10.CHAP_NM
    FROM (
        SELECT  PEMAIN.TRAN_CD
            ,   PEMAIN.TRAN_DT
            ,   PEMAIN.TRAN_NO
            ,   PEMAIN.BILL_NO
            ,   PEMAIN.BILL_DT
            ,   PEMAIN.[RULE]
            ,   CM_MAST.AC_NM
            ,   PEMAIN.CONS_NM
            ,   PEMAIN.NET_AMT
            ,   PEITEM.QTY
            ,   PEITEM.Rate
            ,   PEMAIN.GRO_AMT
            ,   PEITEM.ASSES_AMT
            ,   PEITEM.EXAMTPER
            ,   PEITEM.EXAMT
            ,   PEITEM.CESSPER
            ,   PEITEM.CESS_AMT
            ,   PEMAIN.SHCESSPER
            ,   PEITEM.SHCESS_AMT
            ,   PEITEM.PROD_NM
            ,   CM_MAST.ECC_NO
            ,   CM_MAST.VEND_NM
            ,   PT_MAST.CHAP_NM
        FROM PEMAIN
        JOIN PEITEM ON (PEMAIN.TRAN_CD=PEITEM.TRAN_CD AND PEMAIN.TRAN_ID=PEITEM.TRAN_ID)
        JOIN PT_MAST ON (PEITEM.PROD_CD=PT_MAST.PROD_CD)
        JOIN CM_MAST ON (PEMAIN.AC_ID=CM_MAST.AC_ID)

        UNION ALL

        SELECT  SRMAIN.TRAN_CD
            ,   SRMAIN.TRAN_DT
            ,   SRMAIN.TRAN_NO
            ,   ''
            ,   ''
            ,   SRMAIN.[RULE]
            ,   CM_MAST.AC_NM
            ,   SRMAIN.CONS_NM
            ,   SRMAIN.NET_AMT
            ,   SRITEM.QTY
            ,   SRITEM.Rate
            ,   SRMAIN.GRO_AMT
            ,   SRITEM.ASSES_AMT
            ,   SRITEM.EXAMTPER
            ,   SRITEM.EXAMT
            ,   SRITEM.CESSPER
            ,   SRITEM.CESS_AMT
            ,   SRMAIN.SHCESSPER
            ,   SRITEM.SHCESS_AMT
            ,   SRITEM.PROD_NM
            ,   CM_MAST.ECC_NO
            ,   CM_MAST.VEND_NM
            ,   PT_MAST.CHAP_NM
        FROM SRMAIN
        JOIN SRITEM ON (SRMAIN.TRAN_CD=SRITEM.TRAN_CD AND SRMAIN.TRAN_ID=SRITEM.TRAN_ID)
        JOIN PT_MAST ON (SRITEM.PROD_CD=PT_MAST.PROD_CD)
        JOIN CM_MAST ON (SRMAIN.AC_ID=CM_MAST.AC_ID)
    ) A10
    WHERE A10.TRAN_CD IN ('PE','SR') 
        AND A10.[RULE]='EXCISABLE'
        AND A10.TRAN_DT BETWEEN @SDATE AND @EDATE
        AND A10.AC_NM BETWEEN @SAC AND @EAC
        AND A10.PROD_NM BETWEEN @SIT AND @EIT

END
```

Comment: What did he actually miss?

Comment: @Sivakumar, I can't answer to your question precisely, but, in, this case, I would type the query without using temporary tables.